# dbcontext on add or update it try to add a new application user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I have a model with a foreign key to the application user like:

```
class Student{    
    public int studentID;

    public string fk_userInfo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("fk_userInfo")]
    public ApplicationUser userInfo { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to use

```
dbcontext.Student.AddOrUpdate(model);
```

it shows an error related to the ApplicationUser that it want to create a new user and of course the username is taken!!
I don't want to add a new user of course! I just need to add the student information with the foreign key 
* the model is type of Student

Comment: Did you set the userInfo property of 'model' before AddOrUpdate?

Comment: actually in my get function I get the model information with sub information so I do it like:
studentModel.userInfo = studentModel.userInfo ?? await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userID);

in my HttpPost function the model return with user info as I use hidden fields for both ID and email so I didn't re-get it again

Comment: @Datendenker I think this was the issue, I try to remove my hidden fields which hold some of user info cause it to keep a value when submitting. Now when submitting its null and the add is done thanks for your point.